# How get only number in javascript from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string like

```
-----------------------r1488 | bla bla| blabla -----------
```

and I need get only int( now its 1488), how can I do this with JavaScript?

Comment: Will it always be in that format? That's a pretty vague description.

Comment: Use a regex. Something like `/\d+/` should do it.

Comment: What result would you want from the string "---9---3|7---"?

Comment: Its svn log, always will be like my example. Sorry for stupid question. I will learn regexp and js...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var string = "-----------------------r1488 | bla bla| blabla -----------";
var pattern = /[0-9]+/;
var result = patt.exec(str);
console.log(result[0]);
```

Comment: exec() return array. So you have to add: var n = res[0];

Answer (score 2):

Try with a regex `/\d+/` (if those are only ints, no commas involved):

```
var input= "-----------------------r1488 | bla bla| blabla -----------"
var number = +/\d+/.exec(input)[0]

console.log(number);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace all non-numeric characters by empty string:

```
var str = '-----------------------r1488 | bla bla| blabla -----------';
var repl = str.replace(/\D+/g, "");
//=> 1488
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regex and parseInt:

```
var string = "-----------------------r1488 | bla bla| blabla -----------";
var result = /\d+/.exec(string);

var number = 0;
if (result) {
    number = parseInt(result[0], 10);
}
```